# ¿Cómo aumentar y disminuir el valor que hay en textview atraves de botones usando java en Android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

hola soy nuevo en esto de la programcion en android (JAVA) queria de su gran ayuda

tengo dos botones y un textview  una para aumentar y otra restar
y quiero aumentar el numero  que hay en texto atravez de los botones

este es mi codigo

```
  private static int valor =1; 

   TextView cantidad=view.findViewById(R.id.txtcantidad);
    Button aumentar=view.findViewById(R.id.btnaumntar);
    Button disminuir=view.findViewById(R.id.btndisminuir);
```

lo que no se  como aumentar o disminuir mi textview atraves de los botones

gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo agrega un listener (`OnClickListener`) a los botones, aumentas o disminuyes el valor de la variable. Es importante convertir a String el valor que aumentas o disminuyes usando `String.valueOf(...)`, esto antes de agregarlo a el `TextView`:

```
    TextView cantidad=view.findViewById(R.id.txtcantidad);
    Button aumentar=view.findViewById(R.id.btnaumntar);
    Button disminuir=view.findViewById(R.id.btndisminuir)

    aumentar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(++valor));

        }
    });
    disminuir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cantidad.setText(String.valueOf(--valor));
        }
    });
```

Comment: gracias muy util tu respuesta